# Why, on a linux router, clients can still connect even after the network adapter is down or the iptables routing is disabled?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn, linux-networking

I have a Linux machine which I use as a wireless VPN router. It has a very classic router setup, whose highlights are:

- `openvpn` to connect to the VPN, which is connected to `eth0`, and makes the `tun0` adapter available for tunneled traffic.
- `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE` rule for forwarding the traffic to `wlan0`.

I wanted to entirely block the traffic under certain conditions, but I don't understand why the packets keep flowing even if I remove the above conditions.

For example, if on a client I have a Firefox session open, and I remove the iptables routing rule (`iptables -t nat -F`), something strange happens - some websites still keep working, but the vast majority won't connect.

If I use a bittorrent client, again, something strange happens - when I close the vpn connection (so that `tun0` is dropped), the BT client stops downloading, but plugging `iftop` on the router, after `tun0` is dropped I observer a number of connections showing up from the client machine to a number of internet addresses.

Why this happens?

I have a solution, which is to terminate `hostapd`, but I don't understand why the traffic is so "resilient".

Comment: The `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE` rule forcibly sets the source IP address on all packets coming out via `tun0` to the address currently assigned to that `tun0` adapter. It does not route anything anywhere.  May be that's exactly what you intended to do but your wording in "...rule for forwarding the traffic to wlan0" adjacent to that rule raised a red flag for me.

Comment: As to the Firefox-related symptoms, this looks like a DNS caching effects to me: the sites you've recently viewed and are still having the IPs for their domains in the DNS resolver cache, will work.  Attempting to view those not in the cache will result in DNS queries stalling (waiting for a timeout) and then ultimately failing.

Comment: As to "resilient" traffic, note that IP (the protocol) *is* resilient to network outages by design: the fact you brought some network adapter down does not mean "connections which are made through it" are immediately torn down: simply because *connections are not associated with interfaces **currently** carrying out their traffic.* In IP, the next destination host and the adapter to send the packet via are figured out for each packet individually.  Hence adapters coming in and going away do nothing to TCP sessions, until they time out.

Comment: many thanks for the explanation; if you move this to an answer, I will mark it as replied.

Comment: an additional question - does this imply that there is no (simple) way of entirely blocking the traffic with the wifi client (if not blocking the channel by stopping hostapd)?

Comment: it's unclear to me how exactly your setup is organized, but if what you're basically after for is blocking all traffic coming, say, between `wlan0` and `eth0` you add something like `iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j REJECT` and a pair rule with these interfaces reversed (or you might use IP network addresses instead like `iptables -A FORWARD -s <wifi_subnet_address> -j REJECT` and a pair rule with the `-s` replaced by `-d`).